# C++ project setup with Boost Unit Test and CMake

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I'm starting a greenfield project in C++, using Boost Unit Tests and CMake.  There are several modules which the classes are divided into.

1. What is a recommended structure for the cpp, headers, and unit tests?  Both for directories and for namespaces.
2. How do I tell CMake to run the tests?
3. Do I need to include each file in the CMakeLists or can I do a directory glob?

Comment: Closely related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16857517/cmake-how-to-add-boost-test-cases-with-relative-directories).